# Convert Hash256 String Result to Uppercase?

Tags: c#, php, mysql

I'm trying to get a website Login page and a C# launcher to connect to a MySQL database, my C# code converts a string to SHA256 but in uppercase. So I figured it would be easier to change in PHP, so using `strtoupper` I pass the variable string for the encrypted password. It works great the only problem is this:

```
bec4c38f480db265e86e1650b1515216be5095f7a049852f76eea9934351b9ac - Original
BEC4C38F48DB265E86E1650B1515216BE5095F7A049852F76EEA9934351B9AC - C#
          ^ Right here there is meant to be a 0
```

I'm not sure what's gone wrong as both are using the exact same encryption method and it's odd that it's only one Character... Has anyone experienced this before?

PHP to encrypt text to SHA256 and then strtoupper:

```
$encrypt_password=(hash('sha256', $mypassword));
$s_password = strtoupper($encrypt_password);
```

C# Convert string to SHA256:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256 sha256 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed();
byte[] sha256Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(txtpass.Text);
byte[] cryString = sha256.ComputeHash(sha256Bytes);
string sha256Str = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < cryString.Length; i++)
{
    sha256Str += cryString[i].ToString("X");
}
```

This is the only code that involves encrypting on both sides.

Comment: Can you give some relevant code ?

Comment: I've just edited the post above, thank you for replying.

Comment: I have produced good results with your php code,but unfortunately I am not able to check the C# code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A value like 13 is just "D" not "0D" like would represented in the hash. You need to pad values that are less than 2 digits. Use "X2" as the format string.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty new to using C# for cryptography but this worked a treat.